# Bugs in fscanf/scanf implemintation: incorrect realization of getting double values?

Tags: c++, iostream, scanf

I am trying to get double values from file using fscanf function.
I am running the following code:
this is extract from my code:

```
double some_double;
fscanf(file_name,"%lf", &some_double);
```

for ex. content of file is "10.5"

in debug mode, I see that was read value == 10.0000

What is it: bad implementation of fscanf function, or my mistake?
If second variant - please advice how to fix it?
Kindely thnx

**Edit**

```
#define nameOfFile "infoOnObjects.txt"
#define stop _asm nop
FILE* file = fopen(nameOfFile, "r");
if (file == NULL)
    throw "error";
double num;
int n = fscanf(file,"%lf", &num);
```

Comment: Does that `%some_double` even compile?

Comment: Presuambly the actual code has `&some_double` ?

Comment: yes, sorry whenI wrote post i typed wrong character, in code goes "&"

Comment: Please give us an example `file_name` where you get that.

Comment: I'm guessing that `file_name` isn't actually a string containing the file name, but a `FILE` pointer as returned by `fopen`?

Comment: #define file_name "infoOnObjects.txt"
#define stop _asm nop
FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "r"); 
 if (file == NULL) 
  throw "error";
   
 double num;
 int n = fscanf(file,"%lf", &num);
 stop

Comment: Replace %lf with %Lf. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/34277/ .it may help, im not sure

Comment: What does fscanf return? it returns 10

Comment: Replace %lf with %Lf. - no, it haven`t fixed the problem, the same 10 instead of 10.5 returned

Comment: What does fscanf return?  - sorry, it returns 1, as number of read values from stream

Comment: @spin_eight: Why didn't you just copy+paste code instead of transcribing it?

Comment: Because my code contained private info that I couldn`t post. So I tried to give here the same situation that appeared in my code but with some changes, to hide private data.  As I was in a hurry I made some mistypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your locale symbol for decimal divisor is point '.', not comma ','. This issue is valid on some platforms (Ubuntu gcc, for example; while on Windows mingw it doesn't matters).

Comment: YES!!!! It works!!! Yury, thank you very much!!! You saved a lot of my time! SPASIBO!!!